# How to pass a form data in scrapy shell on command line

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy shell from command line and using
scrapy shell "abcwebsitexyz.com" to test some of my codes and their values but I want to pass form data with it. like I have tried with below

```
scrapy shell "abcwebsitexyz.com", formdata={'username': 'user_name','password':'password',}
```

but it didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the shell directly and later pass the form to a request:

```
$ scrapy shell
```

and inside the shell:

```
>> from scrapy import FormRequest
>> fetch(FormRequest('http://abcwebsitexyz.com', formdata={'username': 'user_name','password':'password',}))
```

as `fetch` uses the current request to update the shell session.